# AWS ECS containers on EC2 are taking different region than the region EC2 is launched in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have an AWS ECS cluster on EC2. The region of ECS cluster and EC2 is us-west-2. But the task container image on running has AWS_REGION environment variable set to a different region in the task container.

Somehow the ecs task role is setting region as us-east-2.

How to have the same region as ECS cluster and EC2 within the ECS task container as well ?

Comment: Can you verify if your task definition has any hard coding for the environment variables.  Another thing is check the DockerFile if that has any hard coding for the other region. Another place could be ecs.config if you are using prebuilt ami. List of env variables available https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html

Comment: No hardcoding anywhere its automatically picking up I believe the default aws region for my account.
Btw I found a solution to my problem now. But a better way is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

One way I figured out is in AWS ECS Service task definition we can add an environment variable AWS_REGION with required value and it works.

I know EC2 and ECS metadata are also options but don't want anything to include is script to read metadata and set AWS_REGION variable.

Mainly need to check if aws provides anything dynamic to have it set by default based on ecs cluster region and ecs cluster ec2 region.